# Fail to download event attachments

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I have an event with attachment which is about 50 MB.

Below requests are fine:

```
GET /users/{id}/events/{id}

GET /users/{id}/events/{id}/attachments/{id}?$select=name,size
```

```json
{
"@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('u_id')/events('e_id')/attachments(name,size)",
"value": [
    {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.fileAttachment",
        "id": "a_id",
        "name": "xxxx",
        "size": 51564506
    }
]
```

}

But when I want to get the content of this attachment:

```
GET /users/{id}/events/{id}/attachments/{id}
```

it returns

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorMessageSizeExceeded",
    "message": "The message exceeds the maximum supported size., The message exceeds the maximum supported size.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "426c3bf3-eda8-40c8-afe6-9b83877a328c",
      "date": "2018-10-24T02:31:48"
    }
  }
}
```

How could I deal with this?

Is it possible to increase the size limit of this API?

Thank you!

Comment: The URLs you've provided are incomplete. Please edit your question and include a minimum viable code sample showing how you're calling the API. It would also be helpful to understand how your tenant is configured, particularly if this is purely Exhcnage Online or an Online/On-Prem Hybrid

Comment: Hi @MarcLaFleur, just updated my post, thanks for your further help.

Answer (score 0):

According to your describe, I suggest you should to limit your attachment size.

Also, Microsoft Graph currently has a 4MB limit. If you want to download large attachment, you need to write custom download logic which will like the breakpoint Continuingly and it doesn’t more than 30MB.

P.S. In general, the attachment size of main stream's mailbox are between 20MB and 30MB.

reference:

[4MB total size of each REST request](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample/issues/18)